# During handling of the above exception (badly formed hexadecimal UUID string), another exception occurred:

Tags: python, django

I have a checkbox list - user check which items to update -

```
<th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" name="document_detail" value="{{ result.id }}"
                                                           id="result_check"/>{{ result.id }}
```

This is handled in view by:

```
 document_request = request.POST['document_detail']
                logging.info(document_request)
                approval_items = []
                for document in document_request:
                    logging.info(document)
```

logging.info gives the correct UUID field e.g. 91da274b-208f-4d65-9e5f-d5cbf2860961

after the loop is initiated the value change to simply "9" or the first character of the UUID.
e.g. logging.info give "9" hence the correct error of badly formed UUID

Is there a correct method of handling this type of item that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I change the floowing line:

```
document_request = request.POST.getlist('document_detail')
```

no error now